# How to manage transactions in Kafka with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, transactions, apache-kafka, bigdata

I use Kafka and spark as an ETL .

I want to use spark sql to persist data in oracle, Can I rollback transaction in spark if transaction failed in between?

E.g. How to make sure certain updates need to be done at the same time? For example in a file we have t1 and t2 data and we want to make the changes to the t1 and t2 at the same time?  Transaction concept?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect for landing data to Oracle, and Kafka Streams or KSQL for your transformations? Kafka Streams supports transactions.

Comment: I use kafka as a messaging system, and I do my treatments and transformations with Spark to write after the result in Oracle , I wonder how can we manage the transactions in this case? Thanks